# lookup in presto using single column against a range in lookup table

Tags: presto

I would like to perform a lookup in presto where table is contains my lookup column "lookup_code" and tableb has a range lookup_range_description that i want to return

TableA

```
# lookup_code  
12  
2333  
50000
```

TableB

```
# start_,end_,lookup_range_description  
2300,4000, AverageCost1  
23300,239900, AverageCost2  
193000,193999, AverageCost3
```

expected result

```
# lookup_code,start_,end_,lookup_range_description  
12,''  
2333,2300,4000, AverageCost1  
50000,23300,239900, AverageCost2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use LEFT OUTER JOIN with BETWEEN like this.

```
select 
 a.lookup_code
 ,b.start_
 ,b.end_
 ,b.lookup_range_description 
from TableA a 
left outer join TableB b 
on a.lookup_code between b.start_ and b.end_
```

```
 lookup_code | start_ |  end_  | lookup_range_description
-------------+--------+--------+--------------------------
          12 |   NULL |   NULL | NULL
        2333 |   2300 |   4000 | AverageCost1
       50000 |  23300 | 239900 | AverageCost2
```